# infinite git pull git remote prune loop - how to fix?

Tags: git, github

My git pull results in

```
error: cannot lock ref 
    'refs/remotes/origin/victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting':  
    'refs/remotes/origin/victor' exists; cannot create 
    'refs/remotes/origin/victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting'
From github.com:deanhiller/webpieces
    ! [new branch]          victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting ->
    origin/victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting  (unable to update local ref)
    error: some local refs could not be updated; try running
    'git remote prune origin' to remove any old, conflicting branches
```

so I run git remote prune origin and then git pull and end up with the same error.

This is all on GitHub, how do I fix it?

More detail.  When I run git branch ->

```
(base) Deans-MacBook-Pro:webpieces dean$ git branch
* master
  submit_dean/generateHttpClient
  submit_dean/googleCloudStorage
  submit_dean/startingFixedSsl
```

Ok, These two branches in my remote repo exist ->

- origin/Victor
- origin/victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting

Notice the case as that was what was screwing things up!!

Comment: what are the results of: `git remote prune origin`? you mentioned that tried it.

Have you verified that you don't have locally branch and remote branch (untracked -no upstream) with the same name locally and on the remote?

Comment: I read one of the "L"s in your last name as a "T" at first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `'refs/remotes/origin/victor' exists; cannot create  'refs/remotes/origin/victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting'`

Git fetched a new branch reference called `victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting` from the remote, but it cannot create the `victor` directory locally because there's already a branch reference called `victor`.

Here's how it looks like on the file system:

```sh
.git/refs/remotes/origin/
|-- victor                          <-- This branch reference exists,
`-- victor                          <-- so Git cannot create this directory
    `-- moreLocalGCPStorageTesting  <-- in order to store this new branch.
```

You could try renaming the local `victor` remote tracking branch to something else. You'd have to do it on the file system, though:

```sh
$ mv .git/refs/remotes/origin/victor .git/refs/remotes/origin/foo
```

If you've checked out the `victor` branch locally, you should also update its upstream reference. Also, keep in mind that the next time you fetch, you are going to receive the `victor` branch again.

A better solution is to ask the author of the `victor` branch to rename it on the upstream repo.

Comment: ironically, I created neither of those branches but Victor created a branch origin/Victor and origin/victor/moreLocalGCPStorageTesting and your post helped me figure that out.